# Можно ли удалить все элементы массива, изменив его длину?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив, содержащий `n` элементов, назовём его `arr`. Могу ли я удалить все элементы таким образом: `arr.length = 0`, или они останутся в памяти?

Comment: как вариант, можете переопределить его как `arr = []`, можно и обнулить длину

Comment: @highpassion дак это произведёт полное удаление всех элементов без каких-либо утечек памяти и пр. или нет?

Comment: нет, это имеет свои особенности, сейчас оформлю ответ

Comment: удалением из памяти занимается сборщик мусора, удаляя элемент из массива - сам элемент никак не меняется. Следовательно, неважен и способ удаления.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удаление методом `splice` - `arr = arr.splice(0, arr.length)` удаляет все элементы массива, но они остаются в памяти, пока сборщик мусора до них не дойдет.

Запись переопределения `arr = []` подходит лишь в тех случаях, когда в других местах кода нет обращений к первоначальному массиву и только лишь переменная `arr` обращается к массиву, в противном случае, остальные переменные не изменят значения и будут работать со старым массивом.

Способ обнуления длины массива - `arr.length = 0` работает точно так же, как и `splice`, элементы остаются в памяти, пока сборщик мусора до них не дойдет.

Comment: splice работает точно также как и изменение длины ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ изменяется сам массив, элементы как были в памяти так и остаются пока их не соберет сборщик мусора.

Comment: @Grundy , спасибо

Comment: @IWProgrammer, не стоило отмечать галочкой некорректный ответ :)

Comment: исправил ответ, могу сделать общественным @Grundy